# How can I understand the Hadwiger conjecture?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I would like to understand the Hadwiger conjecture and I would like to read books that will allow me to both understand it and also get a grasp of the theory it is related to. Regards

Comment: Are you looking for something like a survey paper or do you just want an explanation of what it is?  The motivation and explanation of the Hadwiger conjecture could be explained in an MSE answer.  How much graph theory have you studied?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)) summarizes the statement quite nicely: Does every graph with chromatic number $k$ have $K_k$ as a minor?

Comment: No, I'm a high school student, but I really like to sit down and read math. This problem is very appealing to me and I would like to know the theory and to have the knowledge which is necessary to understand. I think the Hadwiger conjecture is in graph theory. So I bought Bondy's book. However I want a book that goes  in detail into this area of math. Not a graph theory book, but one that covers this specific topic and perhaps discusses discharging or the four color theorem. I want a bibliography that takes me from first year undergrad knowledge to Hadwiger's. Thank you sincerely @AndrewSalmon

Comment: You've asked three very similar questions in succession; I think it's worth pointing out that all of these topics are challenging for _graduate students_ in mathematics.  I really actively admire your zeal here, but you should understand that getting a good grasp of any one of these topics is something that could take literally years of study starting from a baseline undergraduate-level mathematics knowledge.  Enjoy the journey, but don't underestimate its magnitude.

Comment: Does Bondy's book cover it?